# write a regular expression to substitute string like c macro?

Tags: regex

'hello world "hello"'.replace(**regex**,"HELLO")
=>
'HELLO world "hello"'

how to write this **regex** which only substitute 'hello' which is not in quote?

Comment: From that syntax I'm guessing you're using Javascript. You should tag your question with the programming language you're using since not all regex engines are equal.

Comment: what's your language programming?

Comment: This is a classic which is very hard to solve with regex in the general case. Do you need to be able to cope with escaped (say, backslash-escaped) double quotes inside the double-quoted string? Outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Javascript:

```
'hello world "hello"'.replace(/($|[^"])hello(?!")/g,'$1HELLO');
```

Comment: This will fail if there is a quote on any side of hello even if it's ended, for example 'hello hello "hello"' will become 'HELLO hello "hello"', while the OP wanted the middle one to be replaced too in this case.